# Always show autocomplete list, even if search doesn't match

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete field, and on type I go to the PHP/Database to retrieve the matching options.

Thing is, my suggestion list isn't exactly matches of the text. I explain:

Say I type "Jon". My list will bring from the database "John Doe", "Jonatan", etc. Only "Jonatan" will be visible as the suggestion to the input, but I do need them all, because it considers approximation (there's a soundex element on my backend search).

My JavaScript/Ajax code:

```js
function prePatientsList(){
      //I'm limiting search so it only starts on the second character
     if (document.getElementById("name").value.length >= 2) { 

            try
            {
             listExecute.abort();
         }catch(err) {
            null;
         }
            var nome= $("#name").val();
            var nomeList = "";
            listExecute = $.ajax({
                    url: '/web/aconselhamento/Atendimento/PrePacientesAutocomplete',
                    type: "POST",
                    async: true,
                    datatype: 'json',
                    data: { nome: nome}
             }).done(function(data){
              source = JSON.parse(data);
             });
            
            
            $(function() {
             $("input#nome").autocomplete({
                    source: source,
                    // I know I probably don't need this, but I have a similar component which has an URL as value, so when I select an option, it redirects me, and I'll apply you kind answer on both.
                    select: function( event, ui ) {                     
                        ui.item.label;
                    }
                });
            });
     }     

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: My only suggestion is to use regular expressions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions Will still need to do a lot of work to break up the string etc. Good luck :)

Comment: Without seeing your back-end code, it's difficult to say for sure but my guess is that you need to research a better text search implementation. Without Levenshtein distance or n-gram indexing, for example, you might find it difficult to locate close matches. Perhaps check out Elasticsearch or Apache Solr?

Comment: My backend already gives me the correct JSON.
If I type Jon, my suggestion list variable (source in this case) gets the correct values (John Doe, etc).

Problem is: the autocomplete text input will only display the items of the list with an exact match.

My list is a correct match from my soundex, so I need the whole list displayed all the time.

Comment: @ryuzakixd please supply an example of the JSON data that is being returned. Since you're filtering the Source locally from the returned data, it's very basic. If the term is `Jon`, it will not hit on `John`. You will have to create your own algorithm for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd have to set your remote endpoint directly as the autocomplete's source (e.g. similar to https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) so that it's the backend which does all the filtering. Right now, the autocomplete effectively thinks you've fed it a *static* list of options from which further filtering should take place, and therefore it decides to handle the filtering itself.

Your code can be as simple as this I think, no need to have a separate handler or an ajax request outside the scope of the autocomplete.

```
$(function() {
  $("input#nome").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2, //limit to only firing when 2 characters or more are typed
    source: function(request, response) 
    {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/web/aconselhamento/Atendimento/PrePacientesAutocomplete',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { nome: request.term } //request.term represents the value typed by the user, as detected by the autocomplete plugin
     }).done(function(data){
         response(data); //return the data to the autocomplete as the final list of suggestions
     });
    },
    // I know I probably don't need this, but I have a similar component which has an URL as value, so when I select an option, it redirects me, and I'll apply you kind answer on both.
    select: function( event, ui ) {                     
      ui.item.label;
    }
  });
});
```

See http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much!

I'm very sorry on the lateness in my response. I couldn't validate it pronto because I lost access to my environment for a while.

Only change I had to do was:
response(JSON.parse(data));

Comment: @ryuzakixd you shouldn't need to do that - I simply made a typo. `datatype: "json"` should be `dataType: "json"` - and then jQuery takes care of the parsing for you. Then you don't need an extra `JSON.parse` call. I've updated the answer to fix the typo.